# Complex attribute using ActiveResource in Rails 3.2.12

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeresource

I'm trying to convert a webservice response into a object in my Rails application, I'm receiving the following json:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "status": true,
    "password": "123",
    "userType": {
        "description": "description",
        "userTypeId": 1
    },
    "email": "abc@gmail.com"
}
```

I want to convert the userType attribute in a UserType Ruby class like this:

```
class UserType
  attr_accessor :userTypeId, :description
end
```

I'm using ActiveResource to communicate with the webservice, I tried use the attribute method for convert the userType json attribute into UserType class but the attribute method doesn't accept complex types, only string, integer e etc...

How can I convert the userType (webservice response) into UserType Ruby Class?

> Rails 3.2.12 and Ruby 1.9.3p194

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to implement `userType` as an instance method.

```
class MyResource < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://api.example.com/"

  def userType
    UserType.new(userTypeId: super.userTypeId, description: super.description) 
  end
end
```

This works because ActiveResource automatically creates a "getter" method for each of the keys in the attributes hash that you pass into the class constructor. When the called attribute method corresponds to a hash value, ActiveResource returns an instance of an automatically generated class `MyResource::UserType`, which respectively will respond to the `userTypeId` and the `description` methods. You can get hold of this instance by calling `super` within the overridden method, and passing the value of `userTypeId` and `description` to your own class.

**Edit:** 
- Corrected class name

PS: Have a look at the [ActiveResource#load](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#method-i-hash) method for more details on how attribute getter methods get generated.

Comment: Awesome @And! Your solution worked, now I can work with UserType class. I saw that you used ActiveSupport instead ActiveResource, which should I use? What's the difference between them? I tried to use ActiveSupport but I receive a error. Thanks for helping =) !!

Comment: Oops.. there was a typo there. It was actually ActiveResource.